# Bootcamp windows 8.1 not booting

Tags: bootcamp

I recently installed windows 8.1 using bootcamp and it worked well for a few days. For some reason when I turned on my computer it switched to the mac partition. When I turned off the computer and tried to switch to windows, I just got a black screen with no cursor or anything, although it didn't look like the computer was completely shut off. Now, I can easily go on to apple, but whenever I try to use windows I keep getting a black screen with no cursor. I tried searching up what the problem was, but I can't find any solutions.Thanks in advance!

*MacBook Pro with Retina display, OS X El Capitan (10.11.6)*

Answer (score 2):

That’s most likely not related to Mac OS or Bootcamp, but rather a Windows issue. There’s barely enough information from your side to estimate what’s the problem here, but most likely it’s an issue with the windows bootloader. From a Windows install disk or USB stick, open up a command prompt, and execute the commands `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` and `bootrec.exe /fixboot`. These should reinstall the bootloader.

In case that doesn’t work, it’s most likely an issue with your Windows installation. Since Windows isn‘t as repairable as Mac or Linux is, it’s likely that reinstalling windows (save all data, format the partition from disk utility in Mac OS and install from the Windows install media again, as you did in the first place) is the best bet to go.

Anyways, since your question is most likely not related to Apple, you’re good to ask in a Windows QA site like superuser.com how to fix your Windows boot (there’ a lot of answered questions already so just search).